# Skipping cutscenes

Tags: pc, mass-effect

Is there any way to skip cutscenes in the first Mass Effect game? I read somewhere that you could press space repeatedly, but that is not working. I'm having trouble with a post-cutscene fight and I'm annoyed I have to sit through the cutscene every time things go south.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow [this guide](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/PC_Tweaks) at your own risk! Always remember to backup your data before trying.

Anyway, certain cutscenes such as the intro movies are unskippable, so you maybe were trying on those, and spacebar failed.

Comment: That guide covers a lot more ground than just skipping cutscenes. Perhaps including the relevant parts in your answer would be a good idea. Plus it safeguards against potential link rotting. (And no, I'm not that far in -.-)

Comment: I think what Kareen is tactfully trying to say is even with old games it's good to just answer the question and avoid spoilers - some people asking questions about them are playing them for the first time.

Comment: Did i spoil anything? O_o

Comment: Sorry :( I just hid the spoiling part for other people reading, sorry for ruining the game to you :(